# Mover titulo de figura con matplotlib

Tags: python, imagen, matplotlib

Estoy usando matplotlib, tengo que hacer una figura con un segundo eje-x (arriba de la figura), eso me funcionó con el siguiente código. Pero cuando quiero poner título a la figura, éste se superpone con el nombre del eje superior. Alguien sabe como solucionar ésto en éste código? (he buscado soluciones en la web pero como soy nueva en python no se como implementarlas)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

plt.title('Linea H2')

ax1.plot(radioarc, mcv1,'ko')
ax1.set_xlim(-1.65, 1.65)
ax1.set_xlabel("Radius[arcsec]")
ax1.set_ylabel("Velcidad Radial[km/s]")
plt.errorbar(radioarc, mcv1, yerr=sdv1, fmt='None', ecolor='k')

ax2 = ax1.twiny()
ax2.set_xlabel("Radius[pc]")
ax2.set_xlim(-1.65, 1.65)
ax2.set_xticks([-1.48, -1, -0.5, 0,0.5, 1, 1.48])
ax2.set_xticklabels(['-90','-60', '-30', '0', '30', '60', '90'])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Gaia, bienvenid@ a SOes. Este es un sitio en español, asi que porfavor traduce tu pregunta, para que no termine cerrada o en espera.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes colocar el `axes` donde más te convenga para así dejar el espacio a otros elementos. Retocando un poco el código que has puesto:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


mcv1 = np.random.randn(10)
radioarc = np.arange(len(mcv1))

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes((0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5)) # Añado unos 'axes' indicando la 
                                         # posición que quiero que ocupe 
                                         # dentro de la figura. 
                                         # Juega con estos valores

fig.suptitle('Linea H2') # en lugar de usar el `title` del 'axes' uso 
                         # el `suptitle` de la `figure`

ax1.plot(radioarc, mcv1,'ko')
ax1.set_xlim(-1.65, 1.65)
ax1.set_xlabel("Radius[arcsec]")
ax1.set_ylabel("Velcidad Radial[km/s]")

ax2 = ax1.twiny()
ax2.set_xlabel("Radius[pc]")
ax2.set_xlim(-1.65, 1.65)
ax2.set_xticks([-1.48, -1, -0.5, 0,0.5, 1, 1.48])
ax2.set_xticklabels(['-90','-60', '-30', '0', '30', '60', '90'])

fig.show()
```

El resultado sería algo como lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ves hay bastante espacio entre el título de la figura y el título del eje X superior. Ajústalo como consideres.